# Submit URL via AJAX / PHP set variable without refreshing page, load variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm having an issue with some script to perform a function via AJAX without refreshing my page.  I have a field for a user to enter an external URL, and when they click submit it pops up a modal window, with some information generated through a separate PHP page (images.php currently).  I have the script working when the form is actually submitted, the page reloads, and images.php is able to see index.php?url=whatever, but I'm trying to update the page without having to refresh.  Do I need to re-render the DIV after defining the variable?  I think this may be where I'm having problems.

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$("#newNote").submit(function() {

var url = "images.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.
var noteUrl = $('#noteUrl).val();
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: {noteUrl: noteUrl},
       success: function(data)
       {
           alert(data); // show response from the php script.
       }
     });

return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<form id="newNote">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="noteUrl">
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="addNote" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#noteModal" value="Add Note"/>
</form>
```

PHP (aside from form being submitted to this, this is also included in the modal, which opens, but returns NULL on var_dump($postUrl))

```
$postUrl = $_REQUEST['noteUrl'];
echo $postUrl;
```

I could definitely be missing something glaring here, but honestly I've tried every combination of AJAX example I could find on here.  Am I missing a huge step about having PHP get the variable?  Do I need to refresh a DIV somewhere?

Please help.

Comment: Change var noteUrl = $('#noteUrl).val();   to   var noteUrl = $('#noteUrl').val(); - missing quote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a bit neater version of the same code, with the missing quote corrected.

```
$(function() {
    $("#newNote").submit(function() {
        $('#notePreview').empty();
        var url = "images.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.
        var noteUrl = $(this).find('#noteUrl').val();

        var request = $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: {noteUrl: noteUrl}
        });

        request.done(function(data) {
           $('#notePreview').append(data);
        });

        return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    });
});
```

Comment: This is great! Just what I needed.  I added a couple things for the final product, in case anyone sees this thread as an answer for their question.  Thanks, @LShetty.

Comment: @KevinO'Brien, glad I coould help :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the attribute `name="noteUrl"` to your input

```
<form id="newNote">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="noteUrl" id="noteUrl">
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="addNote" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#noteModal" value="Add Note"/>
</form>
```

You can also do `var_dump($_REQUEST);` to see what request variables are being sent.

Comment: I added `name="noteUrl"`, to no avail.  When I var_dump($_REQUEST); I just get: 

`array(3) { ["__utma"]=> string(55) "218755011.1844378823.1395071644.1395071644.1395071644.1" ["__utmc"]=> string(9) "218755011" ["__utmz"]=> string(70) "218755011.1395071644.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)" }`

Comment: What if you `var_dump($_POST)`? Also, use the developer tools tool (F12 key) from your webbrowser to see if the http requests are being sent. Example: http://i.imgur.com/y9WBQsx.png

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in the header information being sent.  `var_dump($_POST)` shows an empty array.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fgJP8/ This code works fine client side, and sends the POST/REQUEST data to the url. Make sure you have `name="noteUrl"` case sensitive.

Comment: Is it possible to have the POST/REQUEST data then load on the same page?  If I `include ('images.php');` can I `echo $noteUrl;` on the same page, all without refreshing?

Comment: And yes, if I change the button or JS to actually submit the form, the data is sent.  I cannot figure out how to have it displayed on the page without refreshing though.

Answer (score 0):

You might have missed the `noteUrl` as name. Try giving the name as below and get it using the same name. In your case it is `noteUrl`

```
<form id="newNote">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="noteUrl" id="noteUrl">
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="addNote" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#noteModal" value="Add Note"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I added `name="noteUrl"` but it did not change anything.

Comment: Are you going to use only one field or multiple field? are you planning to get only noteUrl? In this case just send this value alone in ajax, instead of serialize all fields

Comment: You're right, I've updated my post.  I am still having no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this

```
var noteUrl = $('#noteUrl).val();
```

be

```
var noteUrl = $('#noteUrl').val();
                        ^^^
```